# Accidentally overwriting default bootstrap styling on navbar dropdown

Tags: html, css

Basically I have edited the default bootstrap styling of the nav-bar because I wanted a custom look, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1zDA.png

However, I style wish to invoke the inherited bootstrap styling when the navbar collapses and menu drops down, but it's inheriting the styling from the normal navbar, like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKA8a.png

So really I'm asking is there a better or more descriptive way for me to style the normal horizontal navbar so I don;t stuff up the default bootstrap styling on the dropdown menu.

Here is my CSS that is causing the issue:

```
ul.nav {
    width; 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

.nav li a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 32px 0px 5px;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    color: 
}

.nav ul.nav li {
    display: inline;
    height: 100%
}

.nav ul.nav li a {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px #555 solid; 
}
```

And the associated HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primaryNav" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Bootstrap to Wordpress"></a>   
                    </div><!-- navbar header -->
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="primaryNav">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                          <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- navbar-container -->
            </div><!-- navbar-inner -->
        </div><!-- navbar -->
    </div><!-- navbar-wrapper -->
</header>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks
Heath

Comment: I can't see a trouble here in your code: http://jsfiddle.net/cvmzunwc/
Are you sure that CSS lines are the problem?

Comment: Yes I think I am sure. I have modified these elements .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus. By modifying these it also modifies the style of the vertical menu drop-down which I don't want. I want it to maintain the default bootstrap style but only for the drop-down. I'm not sure what elements to style in CSS to only impact one or the other because everything I try impacts the horizontal and vertical menu styles. Surely, there is a way to style them separately?